# Как получить url изображения товара с wildberries по ссылке на товар?

Tags: python, wildberries

Если перейти в карточку товара на вб и через inspect посмотреть ссылку на изображение, то она будет выглядеть следующим образом: https://basket-10.wb.ru/vol1425/part142562/142562537/images/big/1.webp, где 142562537 будет артикул товара, но вот откуда берется basket-10 не понятно. При этом для разных товаров номер basket будет разный. Можно ли как-то не используя selenium определить номер баскета? Поиск по запросам из network ничего не дал.

Comment: 2 варианта - slice(url) или растащить запрос. Я так понимаю при отправке запроса на загрузку страницы со сторонних серверов приходит разная инфа. Нужно чекать тип входящих запросов и потрошить их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже код на js, но думаю вы разберетесь:
берем артикул
`vol` это артикул деленный на 100000

переменная `vol` - по сути номер basket

*значения подобраны эмпирически, не являются истиной в последней инстанции*

```
// Делает картинки для артикулов
function wb_img_url(input) {
  const nm = parseInt(input, 10),
    vol = ~~(nm / 1e5),
    part = ~~(nm / 1e3);
  let host;
  if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 143) {
    host = "//basket-01.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 144 && vol <= 287) {
    host = "//basket-02.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 288 && vol <= 431) {
    host = "//basket-03.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 432 && vol <= 719) {
    host = "//basket-04.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 720 && vol <= 1007) {
    host = "//basket-05.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1008 && vol <= 1061) {
    host = "//basket-06.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1062 && vol <= 1115) {
    host = "//basket-07.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1116 && vol <= 1169) {
    host = "//basket-08.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1170 && vol <= 1313) {
    host = "//basket-09.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1314 && vol <= 1601) {
    host = "//basket-10.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1602 && vol <= 1655) {
    host = "//basket-11.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1656 && vol <= 1919) {
    host = "//basket-12.wb.ru";
  } else if (vol >= 1920 && vol <= 2045) {
    host = "//basket-13.wb.ru";
  } else {
    host = "//basket-14.wb.ru";
  }

  return `${host}/vol${vol}/part${part}/${nm}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Номер "basket" в URL, скорее всего, представляет собой какой-то внутренний идентификатор корзины или сервера, и он может изменяться для разных сессий или разных товаров. Этот номер, вероятно, генерируется динамически и может быть связан с вашей сессией на веб-сайте.