Python парсинг Вайлдбериз
Всех приветствую, делаю парсер карточек на Вайлдбериз по артиклу
Задумка простая ввожу артикул товара в бота и он выдает мне json по нему, но столкнулся с проблемой, что ссылки на json ВБ дает разные у некоторых товаров
Пример:
Мне нужен card.json у этого товара https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/208285191/detail.aspx
Он находится по этому запросу https://basket-14.wbbasket.ru/vol2082/part208285/208285191/info/ru/card.json
Вот мне нужен basket-14
У других товаров может быть basket-04, basket-10 итд
Думал сделать через try except, но мне кажется есть вариант попроще
Не знаю на сколько тут необходим код: но вот чтобы было понимание

article = input("Введите артикул: ")
part = article[:-3]
vol = article[:-5]

basket = 1

try:
    url_json = f"https://basket-0{str(basket)}.wbbasket.ru/vol{vol}/part{part}/{article}/info/ru/card.json"
    json_data = requests.get(url_json).json()
except:
    try:
        basket = 2
        url_json = f"https://basket-0{str(basket)}.wbbasket.ru/vol{vol}/part{part}/{article}/info/ru/card.json"
        json_data = requests.get(url_json).json()
    except:
        try:
            basket = 3
            url_json = f"https://basket-0{str(basket)}.wbbasket.ru/vol{vol}/part{part}/{article}/info/ru/card.json"
            json_data = requests.get(url_json).json()
        except:
            try:
                basket = 4
                url_json = f"https://basket-0{str(basket)}.wbbasket.ru/vol{vol}/part{part}/{article}/info/ru/card.json"
                json_data = requests.get(url_json).json()
            except:
                basket = 14
                url_json = f"https://basket-{str(basket)}.wbbasket.ru/vol{vol}/part{part}/{article}/info/ru/card.json"
                json_data = requests.get(url_json).json()

print(json_data)```


А вопрос, то, собственно, какой?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1548162/470333
